# Designing full screen image for multiple size android screens

Tags: android, image, android-layout, splash-screen, android-fullscreen

I want to create a full screen image which supports multiple screen sizes in android.

I know that there are 5 different sizes mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, xxxdpi. I also know that creating a **9 patch image** seems to be the ideal solution. The problem is that the Android documentation always talks in dps, and dpis for the different screen densities (mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, xxxdpi) but as a developer at the end of the day I need to make the **image in pixels**.

So to avoid stretching, compression or any other distortion what should be the pixel sizes of the 5 images that I should make? Or are there other images sizes also to be made? I have spent a lot of time on this already, so if anybody has encountered and solved this problem then please post the screen sizes and why those sizes were chosen.

**EDIT:**

Is there any specific link I can refer to. I want the pixel*pixel sizes of the images to make which will handle each case properly. I know they will be approx, but I want good user experience with the least number of images, so that the apk size is small.

Comment: mdpi, hdpi, etc, are *density* specifiers, not *size*. You may have a 1280x800 screen that's 4" at xdpi, or 7" at hdpi. There are significantly more than five resolutions in Android.

Comment: Ultimately, you are going to have to use FITXY as part of the ImageView Scale Type : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: But if you want to get access to the actual pixels, you can use the DisplayMetrics class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: If there are 5 different densities, then what should I design for? My images will be in the center, and it will be a 9 patch to handle stretching. But for xhdpi for example, I made a 720*1280, it got compressed. When I made 720*960, it was small. So similarly, what are the best sizes for all group of sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can get many screen sizes on various devices. If you want the image not being altered and fit the screen exactly the size it is, you would need to create images for all possible screens.
The five groups you mentioned are for densities not for sizes. This is to have your icons and other objects roughly the same physical size across possible devices.
Your are probably looking for [size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Comment: If there are 5 different densities, then what should I design for? My images will be in the center, and it will be a 9 patch to handle stretching. But for xhdpi for example, I made a 720*1280, it got compressed. When I made 720*960, it was small. So similarly, what are the best sizes for all group of sizes?

Comment: Display resolution is not directly tied to the density. Two displays with the same resolution can have different physical dimenstions thus having different density. No matter what you'll end up with images being transformed. You can use [size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) to provide multiple images and Android will pick the most suitable.